# SQL Server SELECT Sequential Data, Breaking Lines at any Column Diference

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I posted a question at MSDN (Brazilian) site. My problem is that I want to make a select at a table that returns a first and last number (from a column) WITHOUT INTERRUPTION and WITHOUT CHANGES on other columns related on the search.

**QUESTION UPDATE (2015-04-23)**

I've updated my own post on MSDN as on this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/b23b33b0-7b06-44c5-9145-63b4523cf5c3/select-de-linhas-consecutivas-incrementais-reaberto?forum=520#a98d4a2e-0e0c-4c7d-b1c8-7f29a7e71ff0). I made a SELECT that would give me almost what i want - but 1 line for the first and 1 line for the final number on each range. It is breaking perfectly, so when the `Diag` column is `O` (letter O) means that there is no other number on the range (as O stands for "Only"), so the number would be both initial and final. When the `Diag` column ins ´F´ is the first number of the range, and due to the ´ORDER BY´ arguments, the last number of that range (as you may guess, with an ´L´ for LAST on the `Diag` column) is right below it, on the next line. My task now is to create 1 more column on it and then repeated the `enNumber` field when `Diag` is `O`, place the next line ´enNumber´ value when the ´Diag´ column where ´F´ and eliminate all lines with ´L´ on the ´Diag´ column.

```
SELECT
  [EnT].enPrefix,
  [EnT].enNumber,
  [EnT].enOrder,
  [EnT].enDate,
  [EnT].enNfe,
  [EnT].enClient,
  (CASE
     WHEN [EnN].enNumber IS NULL THEN
       CASE
         WHEN [EnP].enNumber IS NULL THEN 'O'
         ELSE 'L'
       END
     ELSE 'F'
   END) AS [Diag]
FROM
  SerialsDB.dbo.Entries AS [EnT]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SerialsDB.dbo.Entries AS [EnN]
    ON ([EnT].enProduct = [EnN].enProduct) AND
       ([EnN].enNumber = [EnT].enNumber + 1) AND
       ([EnN].enOrder = [EnT].enOrder) AND
       ([EnN].enClient = [EnT].enClient) AND
       ([EnN].enNfe = [EnT].enNfe) AND
       ([EnN].enDate = [EnT].enDate)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SerialsDB.dbo.Entries AS [EnP]
    ON ([EnT].enProduct = [EnP].enProduct) AND
       ([EnP].enNumber = [EnT].enNumber - 1) AND
       ([EnP].enOrder = [EnT].enOrder) AND
       ([EnP].enClient = [EnT].enClient) AND
       ([EnP].enNfe = [EnT].enNfe) AND
       ([EnP].enDate = [EnT].enDate)
WHERE
  ([EnT].enOrder IS NOT NULL) AND
  ([EnT].enClient IS NOT NULL) AND
  (([EnP].enNumber IS NULL) OR
   ([EnN].enNumber IS NULL))
ORDER BY
  [EnT].enOrder ASC,
  [EnT].enDate ASC,
  [EnT].enNfe ASC,
  [EnT].enPrefix ASC,
  [EnT].enNumber ASC
```

Help!

Comment: It would help if you include the structure of the sql tables that you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've wrote a query and got the results i was trying to find. I still don't like it very much as i think it will have a big cost on the database to run it, and i'd like to find one simpler. But anyway, the "problem" it self is resolved.

The resulting query is writen as follows:

```
SELECT
[Pre].[pfPrefix],
[Pro].[prId],
[Pro].[prName],
(CASE
   WHEN [EnP].[enNumber] IS NULL THEN [EnT].[enNumber]
   ELSE
     (SELECT TOP 1
        [iET].[enNumber]
      FROM
        [SerialsDB].[dbo].[Entries] AS [iET]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [SerialsDB].[dbo].[Entries] AS [iEP]
        ON (([iEP].[enProduct] IS NULL AND [iET].[enProduct] IS NULL) OR
            ([iEP].[enProduct] = [iET].[enProduct])) AND
           (([iEP].[enOrder] IS NULL AND [iET].[enOrder] IS NULL) OR
            ([iEP].[enOrder] = [iET].[enOrder])) AND
           (([iEP].[enClient] IS NULL AND [iET].[enClient] IS NULL) OR
            ([iEP].[enClient] = [iET].[enClient])) AND
           (([iEP].[enNfe] IS NULL AND [iET].[enNfe] IS NULL) OR
            ([iEP].[enNfe] = [iET].[enNfe])) AND
           (([iEP].[enDate] IS NULL AND [iET].[enDate] IS NULL) OR
            ([iEP].[enDate] = [iET].[enDate])) AND
           (([iEP].[enAuth] IS NULL AND [iET].[enAuth] IS NULL) OR
            ([iEP].[enAuth] = [iET].[enAuth])) AND
           (([iEP].[enStatus] IS NULL AND [iET].[enStatus] IS NULL) OR
            ([iEP].[enStatus] = [iET].[enStatus])) AND
           ([iEP].[enNumber] = ([iET].[enNumber] - 1))
      WHERE
        (([iET].[enProduct] IS NULL AND [EnT].[enProduct] IS NULL) OR
         ([iET].[enProduct] = [EnT].[enProduct])) AND
        (([iET].[enOrder] IS NULL AND [EnT].[enOrder] IS NULL) OR
         ([iET].[enOrder] = [EnT].[enOrder])) AND
        (([iET].[enDate] IS NULL AND [EnT].[enDate] IS NULL) OR
         ([iET].[enDate] = [EnT].[enDate])) AND
        (([iET].[enClient] IS NULL AND [EnT].[enClient] IS NULL) OR
         ([iET].[enClient] = [EnT].[enClient])) AND
        (([iET].[enNfe] IS NULL AND [EnT].[enNfe] IS NULL) OR
         ([iET].[enNfe] = [EnT].[enNfe])) AND
        (([iET].[enAuth] IS NULL AND [EnT].[enAuth] IS NULL) OR
         ([iET].[enAuth] = [EnT].[enAuth])) AND
        (([iET].[enStatus] IS NULL AND [EnT].[enStatus] IS NULL) OR
         ([iET].[enStatus] = [EnT].[enStatus])) AND
        ([iET].[enNumber] <= [EnP].[enNumber]) AND
        ([iEP].[enNumber] IS NULL)
      ORDER BY
        [iET].[enNumber] DESC)
 END) AS [Initial],
[EnT].[enNumber] AS [Final],
[EnT].[enOrder],
[EnT].[enDate],
[EnT].[enNfe],
[EnT].[enClient],
[Cli].[clGroup],
[EnT].[enAuth]
FROM
[SerialsDB].[dbo].Entries AS [EnT]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [SerialsDB].[dbo].[Entries] AS [EnN]
  ON ([EnN].[enProduct] = [EnT].[enProduct]) AND
     ([EnN].[enOrder] = [EnT].[enOrder]) AND
     ([EnN].[enClient] = [EnT].[enClient]) AND
     (([EnN].[enNfe] IS NULL AND [EnT].[enNfe] IS NULL) OR
      ([EnN].[enNfe] = [EnT].[enNfe])) AND
     ([EnN].[enDate] = [EnT].[enDate]) AND
     ([EnN].[enStatus] = [EnT].[enStatus]) AND
 ([EnN].[enAuth] = [EnT].[enAuth]) AND
 ([EnN].[enNumber] = ([EnT].[enNumber] + 1))
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [SerialsDB].[dbo].[Entries] AS [EnP]
  ON ([EnP].[enProduct] = [EnT].[enProduct]) AND
     ([EnP].[enOrder] = [EnT].[enOrder]) AND
     ([EnP].[enClient] = [EnT].[enClient]) AND
     (([EnP].[enNfe] IS NULL AND [EnT].[enNfe] IS NULL) OR
      ([EnP].[enNfe] = [EnT].[enNfe])) AND
     ([EnP].[enDate] = [EnT].[enDate]) AND
     ([EnP].[enStatus] = [EnT].[enStatus]) AND
 ([EnP].[enAuth] = [EnT].[enAuth]) AND
     ([EnP].[enNumber] = ([EnT].[enNumber] - 1))
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [SerialsDB].[dbo].[Prefixes] AS [Pre]
  ON ([EnT].[enPrefix] = [Pre].[pfId])
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [SerialsDB].[dbo].[Products] AS [Pro]
  ON ([EnT].[enProduct] = [Pro].[prId])
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [SerialsDB].[dbo].[Clients] AS [Cli]
  ON ([EnT].[enClient] = [Cli].[clId])
WHERE
([EnT].[enOrder] IS NOT NULL) AND
([EnT].[enClient] IS NOT NULL) AND
([EnN].[enNumber] IS NULL) AND
([EnT].[enStatus] = 4) AND
([EnT].[enAuth] IS NOT NULL)
```

Thank you Amir for the great inputs, and for Stamen for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to be a simple query using a `GROUP BY`.

For simplicity and to show the basic idea I assume `Entries` table just got two columns: `enNumber` and `enProduct`. You can add all other columns and criteria later.

```
CREATE TABLE [Entries](
    [enNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [enProduct] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Entries] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([enNumber] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO [Entries] VALUES (1000309,2768)
INSERT INTO [Entries] VALUES (1000310,2768)
INSERT INTO [Entries] VALUES (1000311,2768)
INSERT INTO [Entries] VALUES (1000312,2768)
INSERT INTO [Entries] VALUES (1000313,2768)
INSERT INTO [Entries] VALUES (1000314,2768)
INSERT INTO [Entries] VALUES (1000315,2768)
INSERT INTO [Entries] VALUES (1000316,2768)
INSERT INTO [Entries] VALUES (1000317,2768)
/* interrupt */
INSERT INTO [Entries] VALUES (1001388,3328)
INSERT INTO [Entries] VALUES (1001389,3328)
INSERT INTO [Entries] VALUES (1001390,3328)
INSERT INTO [Entries] VALUES (1001391,3328)
INSERT INTO [Entries] VALUES (1001392,3328)
/* change */
INSERT INTO [Entries] VALUES (1001393,3743)
INSERT INTO [Entries] VALUES (1001394,3743)
INSERT INTO [Entries] VALUES (1001395,3743)
INSERT INTO [Entries] VALUES (1001396,3743)
/* change */
INSERT INTO [Entries] VALUES (1001397,3328)
INSERT INTO [Entries] VALUES (1001398,3328)
INSERT INTO [Entries] VALUES (1001399,3328)
INSERT INTO [Entries] VALUES (1001400,3328)
/* interrupt */
INSERT INTO [Entries] VALUES (1003000,2768)
/* change */
INSERT INTO [Entries] VALUES (1003001,3328)
INSERT INTO [Entries] VALUES (1003002,3328)
INSERT INTO [Entries] VALUES (1003003,3328)
GO
```

Create two views, one of them giving all the records that act as the initial of a group and another view for the finals.

A record is an initial/final record if the previous/next `enNumber` does not exist (an interrupt) or has different values (a change).

```
CREATE VIEW [Initials] AS
SELECT E.enNumber
FROM Entries E 
LEFT JOIN Entries E2 on E2.enNumber = E.enNumber - 1
  AND E2.enProduct= E.enProduct
WHERE E2.enNumber IS NULL
GO

CREATE VIEW [Finals] AS
SELECT E.enNumber
FROM Entries E 
LEFT JOIN Entries E2 on E2.enNumber = E.enNumber + 1
  AND E2.enProduct= E.enProduct
WHERE E2.enNumber IS NULL
GO
```

Each record in `Initials` has a counterpart in `Finals` with an `enNumber` equal or greater than its `enNumber`.

```
SELECT i.enNumber AS Initial, E.enProduct 
FROM Initials i 
LEFT JOIN Entries E ON E.enNumber = i.enNumber

SELECT f.enNumber AS Final, E.enProduct 
FROM Finals f 
LEFT JOIN Entries E ON E.enNumber = f.enNumber

Initial enProduct
1000309 2768
1001388 3328
1001393 3743
1001397 3328
1003000 2768
1003001 3328

Final   enProduct
1000317 2768
1001392 3328
1001396 3743
1001400 3328
1003000 2768
1003003 3328
```

You can combine these two views in different ways to achieve the desired results:

```
SELECT i.enNumber AS initial, MIN(f.enNumber) AS final, E.enProduct
FROM Initials i
LEFT JOIN finals f ON f.enNumber >= i.enNumber
LEFT JOIN Entries E ON E.enNumber = i.enNumber
GROUP BY i.enNumber, E.enProduct
ORDER BY i.enNumber

initial final   enProduct
1000309 1000317 2768
1001388 1001392 3328
1001393 1001396 3743
1001397 1001400 3328
1003000 1003000 2768
1003001 1003003 3328
```

Comment: Amir, thanks - i did your code but adapted a bit, still not finding the proper results. Since the explanation was too big for comment, i posted on MSDN a comment (mentioning you) - see this link [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/b23b33b0-7b06-44c5-9145-63b4523cf5c3/select-de-linhas-consecutivas-incrementais-reaberto?forum=520#a6b8c99c-b464-4807-8012-adae5333616f)

Comment: You are missing the change criteria; You have to include and compare all other fields that affect your `GROUP BY` along with `enProduct` in those views, because you want to catch a change in `enOrder, enPrefix, enClient, enDate, enOrder, enNfe` too.

Comment: Not exacty - you see, i placed then all on the `GROUP BY` clause, but for example - `enDate` and `enOrder` will ALWAYS CHANGE TOGETHER, so it's impossible ofr a `enOrder` 3768 be anything else then `enDate` 2015-01-01 (imaginary here, not actual data).

Comment: I suggest you to create the views based on your fields and test with your data to check their results separately before merging with your main query.

Comment: Most certently Amir, that code i wrote on MSDN is entirely out (using the SELECT's inside instead of views) because i used it on a test database - copy of my main one.

Comment: My reply was because i didn't understood what you meant by "missing criteria" - for that, i see the only actual change that affect anything at all would be that `enPrefix` ties up `pfId`, `pfPrefix` that ties up ´prId´ and `prName` and `enDate`, `enNfe`, `enClient` and `clGroup` can only change if `enOrder` changes - can't exist a ´enOrder´ with 2 diferente ´enNfe´ for example.

Comment: I've updated my question once again - removed a lot of text so it would be shorter for anyone else that tries to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this with subquery. In the subquery, you will get the min and max values and include the columns you want to sort by. In the main query, you will select all columns. See the following link for details:

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Section "Selecting the one maximum row from each group"

Comment: Thank you for your response, but i read the link and didn't see how could i apply to my problem.